# In ubuntu 20.04, how to fix pip path?

Tags: package-management, python3, pip

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Every time I try to install a package using pip I get a weird error.

```
pip3 install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-20.0.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv is installed in '/home/mark/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed virtualenv-20.0.21
```

How can I fix this error, please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My answer fixed the issue but shouldn't have been the right answer.
If you happened to be here because you are currently facing the very same issue that OP met, please refer to [Dreamer answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307381/996009) first (and comments)

---

virtualenv is not in your `PATH` for some reason (not properly installed ? I believe it should be in your `/user/local/bin/` or `/user/bin/`, I see you didn't use sudo ?). You can add it to your PATH with

```
echo "export PATH=\"/home/mark/.local/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Edit : `pip3 install PKG --no-warn-script-location` to use the flag to ignore the warning

Comment: Thanks, now it's working perfectly fine. One more thing can you please explain what the above line did, I'm new in Ubuntu.

Thanks once again.

Comment: PATH is directory where the commands you type on the terminal are. Here, you add the directory where virtualenv are, (`echo "helloworld" >> file.txt` add "helloworld" to the end of file.txt) to the `.bashrc` file, kind of "setting of your terminal", then reload it. Therefore the CLI as memorized the PATH.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. See @Dreamer's answer.

Comment: I do agree @Sebastian-Nielson for that. I didn't know why virtualenv/ wasn't in PATH and Dreamer got the point.

Answer (score 23):

On Ubuntu 20.04 simply log out of your account and log back in to fix that warning.  This will re-evaluate your `~/.profile`, which in turn automatically adds the `~/.local/bin` folder to your path *if it exists* (which it does now, but probably hasn't before your first run of `pip3 install`).

After logging back in, `virtualenv` should work as expected and later runs of `pip3` should not raise that warning anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I was annoyed that I need to add stuff to path manually, unlike in older versions - glad I saw this before manually running the command in the accepted answer.

Comment: You don't have to log and out of your account, simply run `. ~/.profile` instead; this is much quicker way of reevaluating your .profile file.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen indeed, but it only affects your current terminal session, not other concurrent ones nor future ones. So technically, it's a workaround and not a permanent fix.