# Python libraries installation

Tags: python3

I am getting this after installing opencv and my file isn't running what should I do?

```
WARNING: The script f2py is installed in '/home/jitendra/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ubuntu 20.04, how to fix pip path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242234/in-ubuntu-20-04-how-to-fix-pip-path)